# Consistent querystring across all links

Tags: php, javascript, html

On every page of my site there is a filter that a user can choose from. Lets call this option1, option2 and option3. This filter is a link that when clicked appends the querystring into the url as such www.mysite.com/?option2.

The problem is that this querystring does not persist into other pages once you start to navigate. ?option2 gets lost along the way.

My question: How can I append the current querystring into the links of that current page until I change it?

Say if on one page I chose option2, then my menu links would look like something like this www.mysite.com/menu1/title?option2, www.mysite.com/menu1/title?option2, etc. and all other links on that page until I choose another filter.

I prefer a PHP solution but wouldn't mind js as well.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write a comment, not an answer. Try with cookies or phpsessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with cookies.
Here's a little tutorial:
http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/qt/php_cookie.htm

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob sorry. But how do I store this value in a cookie and access it?